# rspec 3.0 stubbing syntax - not sure if correct

Tags: ruby, stub, rspec3

I'm trying to get to grips with the new allow syntax (for stubbing) in rspec 3.0 and would really appreciate someone looking at my code and telling me whether it's right(or wrong).

**download.rb**

```
class Download
  def download_file
    # code to download a file 
  end

  def valid_json
    # code to verify downloaded file is file type json
  end
end
```

**download_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'json_spec'  

describe Download do 
  let(:download)  {Download.new}

  describe "#download_file" do
    it 'downloads a file from remote file location ' do
      allow(download).to receive(:exist).and_return(true)
      download.download_file
      expect(download).to have_received(:exist).and_return(true)    
    end 
  end   

  describe "#valid_json" do
    it 'confirms downloaded file is JSON' do
      # download.to_json.should have_json_path("id")
      # download.to_json.should have_json_type(Integer).at_path("id")
      expect(download.to_json).to have_json_path("id")
      expect(download.to_json).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path("id")
    end 
  end
end
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using the correct syntax for stubbing in RSpec 3.0 but I question your motive for using it in this case. I highly recommend you check out Sandi Metz's presentations on Ruby testing which will hopefully help clarify the appropriate case to actually use a stub. Here's Sandi's [Magic Tricks of Testing](https://speakerdeck.com/skmetz/magic-tricks-of-testing-railsconf) slide deck.

Based on the name of your test, it seems that what you really should be testing is whether a file object was created as the result of this method. That's the only thing you should care about--the direct public side effect of sending the `#download_file` message to the `download` object. Anything beyond that means your testing the *implementation* and not the *interface*.

```
describe Download do 
  let(:download) { Download.new }

  describe "#file" do
    context "before file has been downloaded" do
      it "returns nil" do
        expect(download.file).to be_nil
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#download_file" do
    it 'downloads a file from remote file location ' do
      # incoming command message to object under test
      download.download_file
      # assert direct public side effect
      expect(download.file).to be_a File
    end 
  end   
end
```

**EDIT:** One thing I forgot to mention is that you may need to clarify either your question here or your conception about your tests as to whether these are intended as unit tests or integration tests. That could change the answer.

Comment: Hi dnunez24, funny you should say that about Sandi Metz's presentation as I only just watched her talk about this topic on YouTube this morning! I probably wasn't clear enough with my code, but the test for the download method was actually supposed to test for the existence of the file created as a result of the download implementation. I will go back and look at Sandi's deck again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, good. So what you may actually need to be stubbing, then, is whatever code actually fetches and creates the File. Especially if it could be a time consuming while running your tests. It was difficult for me to give a good example of that without understanding the other dependencies involved in your code. You may want to take a look at dependency injection so that you can send stubs into your method calls much easier. I believe Sandi gives some examples of that as well.